# How to use "where" to get parent of parent that has attribute of XYZ

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using `ajax-datatables-rails`, I am trying to get records that are children of a parent model.

For example, I have a parent model named `School`, which has many `teachers`, each of which has many `students`.

If I am using `Student.joins(:teacher)`, but teacher belongs to school, how can I write this so that it only pulls back the students that belong to teachers which belong to a certain school.

I am trying to find a way to do something like: `Student.joins(:teacher => [:school where school_name == "hello world"])` although I know this isn't the right syntax.

Here's the model structure:

```
# app/models/school.rb
class School < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :teachers
end
```

.

```
# app/models/teacher.rb
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :school
    has_many :students
end
```

.

```
# app/models/student.rb
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :teacher
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the joins first and then filter on the table you're interested in:

```
Student.joins(teacher: :school).where(schools: { name: "hello world" })
```

Comment: Sorry for my misguiding example. I will be looking for a specific attribute from `School` other than its ID. So for example, `school_name`.

Comment: Thanks so much man! This actually works perfectly. I do have ONE more question if that's OK. What if I was nesting up one extra model? For example, Exam belongs to Student, which belongs to Teacher, which belongs to School, and at the end result, I want to get those records that ultimately end up with schools that have school_name "hello world"? So just one extra layer? How would that joins look?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `has_many through` association to achieve this. [Reference](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association)

> app/models/school.rb

```
class School < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :teachers
  has_many :students, through: :teachers
end
```

> app/models/teacher.rb

```
class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :school
    has_many :students
end
```

> app/models/student.rb

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :teacher
end
```

So let's say you want to get students list of a particular school can query like.

```
School.find_by_name('ABC School').students
```

Comment: Thanks! This actually helps with one of my examples as well since I was getting another error with ajax-datatables-rails